# unable to make html table column fixed size (not auto expand according to Data)

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have above **data table**. Now the problem is when data coming from backend is very much it expand and make the table awkard.

**I want to wrap whole data in particular fixed column size.** colmn should not be expanded.
My html code is like:

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="datatable" class="pretty searchtabel">
  <thead>
    <tr class="ac-trHd serchtr">
      <!-- this is the colmn(subject) which I want to restrict to expand -->
      <th class="padng10">Subject</th> 
      <!-- other clumn headers -->
    </th>
  </thead>
   <tr>
     <td class="padng10"><s:property value="subject" /></td>
     <!-- other td -->
   </tr>
</table>
```

Plz help.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You missed a closing tag of tr

Comment: no this is just copy paste mistake... tr is closed properly

Comment: Can you fix it on the question?

Comment: Btw "Work Item/Tasks" won't have a value like that in real life :) If you seperate that with a space it would be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

To have fixed column widths, use `table-layout: fixed;` in your CSS.

Comment: First I thought of this aswell but the problem lies in the "text-is-sticky-and-will-expand-cause-no-whitespace" problem (see his image). You could also just set the widths of each individual td. If you do this the text will draw over the rest of the table even when the sibling td's are as big as they should be. But the answer is good as such. :)

Comment: @F.Müller Add `word-wrap: break-word;`, but it will also break other words ant random place (it will break where it needs to break)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5084duow/2/ word-wrap does not work when you have no whitespaces (which is rarely the case) I just mentioned this cause of his image. But you are right for the "standard" case.

Comment: I tried "table-layout:fixed" , now column size doesn't expand but data is overlapping all column next to Subject.

Comment: @AbhishekRajawat yes the problem is that if you have no whitespaces it will not break the text it will just expand to the right. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/5084duow/2/

Comment: @F.Müller It's `word-wrap`, not `text-wrap`

Comment: @F.Muller, yes I got your point, I need to give white space. Its ok. But Actually this was test scenario made my tester, if user typed like this, table will badly messed.

Answer (score 0):

use this CSS

```
      . padng10{

   width:70px;
   text-overflow:ellipsis;
     overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

Comment: for this-- class="padng10"  and also give some width to that div